# Qtip plugin, how to reposition the tooltip

Tags: jquery, plugins, qtip

I have a tooltip attached to a panel that can slide down on the screen when it is clicked.  If I click that panel, the tooltip doesn't reposition, but if I then scroll any amount, the position of the tooltip fixes itself.  The is true for their demos as well.  I'm assuming there's a reposition function in the plugin, but i'm having troubles finding it.

Comment: This question is totally unanswerable. What plugin are you talking about? What have you tried? What does you page structure look like? Geeze man.

Comment: The qtip jquery plugin, as I've said in the title, my page structure is irrelevant, because as I've said, this is the default behavior on this tool tip.  You can view their plugin demo here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/position/corner#

Comment: Your structure is relevant because we don't know what your panel looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If scrolling fixes the problem, then you can always trigger a dummy scroll event like this:

`$(window).trigger('scroll');`